# ng: command not found after installing node and angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I just got a new clean MacOS Catalina installation, and I was trying to get my old project running using ng serve but it tells me that '`ng: command not found`' I installed the npm 6.12.1 through nodeJS 12.13.1 installation as well, and ran 'npm install -g @angular/cli' and both ran without issues, then ran the npm i command for the stuff included in package.json in the same project directory, I googled around and one comment suggested using `npm link @angular/cli` which didn't differ as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your terminal after running `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: Make sure your $PATH includes the location of your npm global modules.

Answer (score 0):

Add npm global modules folder to your `$PATH` variable with the following command

`export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"`